# Using Flexbox "justify-content: space-between" when number of row items varies

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently, I'm using Flexbox `justify-content: space-between` to align items horizontally on collections pages.

However, not all collections have enough items to fill a row. In such a situation, I'd like the first two items to be in the same horizontal position as the first two items on a collections page with enough items to fill a row.

I could use margins on each item instead of using `justify-content: space-between`, but I'm hoping there is a way solve this with Flexbox.

```css
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}

.item {
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
// some collections pages have enough items to fill a row like this
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

// other collections pages don't have enough items to fill a row and have this situation
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about CSS grid ?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but I was hoping to come up with solution within Flexbox.

Comment: it's always from 1 to 4 items ?

Comment: It varies. The point is, sometimes there are enough items to fill the row and other times there is empty space left that the items move into.

Comment: you just accepted the below answer so it's "always from 1 to 4 items"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with flexbox without using some huge work around.
Instead use display grid.

```css
.flex-container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)
}

.item {
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
// some collections pages have enough items to fill a row like this
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

// other collections pages don't have enough items to fill a row and have this situation
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```